# Visualization of charts using real time data from MSSQL with node.js webserver

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, chart.js, handlebars.js

I want to extend my IoT project in order to visualize my incoming IoT data in real time.

**What I have done so far:**

Web server based on hapi.js connected to SQL-Server via Node.js.
The server listens within the network and is able to receive API data pushed via HTTP and store it in a MS SQL database. Currently, the data is displayed via an HTML page using a HTML template engine (handlebars).

**What I want to extend:**

The incoming IoT data should be displayed in a chart via a HTML page. Preferably in real time.

I would like to use chart.js or an equivalent JavaScript library.

**What is the Issue:**

I am not sure if my plans can be realized with JavaScript (Node.js) only. If yes, can I use handlebars to templating the data in the charts?

How should I start?

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js will work fine for your use case.  You can use [chart update](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html) capabilities to add/remove datapoints.  If you want a nice package for doing this, along with some configuration options, you can use [chartjs-plugin-streaming](https://github.com/nagix/chartjs-plugin-streaming).

In order to have your chart update in realtime as the user remains on the page, it is not enough to use Handlebar templates.  You should build an API endpoint on your node server that returns the latest data.

It sounds like you already know how to create routes in [hapi.js](https://hapi.dev/tutorials/?lang=en_US#-adding-routes).  Look into [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or similar in order to send a request to your route from the client.  The response will contain latest data and the client will put the new data into the chart.